# Why does the "geometry" parameter not appear in the response from the aws rekognition detect-custom-labels command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-rekognition

Hello I am trying to use the [DetectCustomLabels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_DetectCustomLabels.html) service from AWS rekognition to get the prediction of a label detecting model but I can not get a response with the geometry parameter.

I try using the `aws rekognition detect-custom-labels` command following the [`detect-custom-labels` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rekognition/detect-custom-labels.html)

```
aws rekognition detect-custom-labels \
 --project-version-arn "arn:aws:rekognition:us-east-2:257838013610:project/dog_cat_test/version/dog_cat_test.2023-12-10T17.13.12/1702246396893" \
 --image '{"S3Object": {"Bucket": "dog-cat-bucket", "Name": "cats.jpeg"}}' \
 --region us-east-2 \
 --min-confidence 0
```

and from the reading on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_DetectCustomLabels.html#API_DetectCustomLabels_ResponseSyntax) I understand that the response from this request is composed by an object with "Name", "Confidence" and "Geometry", but I only get the `Name` and `Confidence` parameters when I execute the command:

```json
{
    "CustomLabels": [
        {
            "Name": "cat",
            "Confidence": 96.12000274658203
        },
        {
            "Name": "dog",
            "Confidence": 3.880000114440918
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have any idea of how to get this geometry parameter on the response from this service? Or what service could help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According [to the documentation on DetectCustomLabels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_DetectCustomLabels.html#API_DetectCustomLabels_ResponseSyntax), you will only get that location information if it exists.

> For each object that the model version detects on an image, the API
> returns a (CustomLabel) object in an array (CustomLabels). Each
> CustomLabel object provides the label name (Name), the level of
> confidence that the image contains the object (Confidence), and object
> location information, if it exists, for the label on the image
> (Geometry). Note that for the DetectCustomLabelsLabels operation,
> Polygons are not returned in the Geometry section of the response.

It also [says that you will only get the bounding box](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/customlabels-dg/detecting-custom-labels.html) if the model you are using is trained to return bounding boxes.

> Custom labels are returned in an array of Custom Label objects. Each
> custom label represents a single object, scene, or concept found in
> the image. A custom label includes:
>
> A label for the object, scene, or concept found in the image.
>
> A bounding box for objects found in the image. The bounding box coordinates show where the object is located on the source image. The
> coordinate values are a ratio of the overall image size. For more
> information, see BoundingBox. DetectCustomLabels returns bounding
> boxes only if the model is trained to detect object locations.
>
> The confidence that Amazon Rekognition Custom Labels has in the accuracy of the label and bounding box.

Can you confirm that your model supports the bounding box?